# Windows 7 Faking Internet Connection

Tags: windows-7, internet, connection, internet-connection

I am having a problem from this blog post: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

I have a dns server set up that I make my windows machine point to as per this : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/change-tcp-ip-settings

After setting up what dns server the windows machine points to, windows checks whether the dns server is working properly by resolving www.microsoft.com (as I saw in Wireshark), and I have setup my server to resolve it. The troubleshooter says there is no issue with the server.

However, contrary to the blog post, My machine never attempts to get the http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt  or resolve dns.msftncsi.com. Instead, it simply tries to resolve a root server, and when I give an IP for it, it tries to resolve the root server from a different dns server setup on my network (one that the windows machine shouldn't be aware of anymore) which cannot resolve it.

It may be that windows isn't checking the internet connection at all and that resolving root has nothing to do with it, but I don't know what to do now. It may be worth mentioning that I do not actually have internet access on my test network.